# Use tcpdump to capture TCP transmitted data withouth the protocol's details (similar to tcpflow)

Tags: linux, tcp, tcpdump

I use `tcpflow` a lot to capture data transmitted as part of TCP connections. It allows you to see the transmitted data without any of the TCP protocol details.

**Is there a way to accomplish the same thing using `tcpdump`?**

I mean, I was able to see the transmitted  data using `tcpdump` as well, but including all the contents of the packets which I'm not interested in. I just want the plain data without any of the protocol's details.

This is what I mean:

For instance, sending a "hello world" like this:

```
echo "hello world" | nc localhost 8098
```

Using `tcpflow`, I can accomplish this output:

```
sudo tcpflow -C -i any port 8098
tcpflow: listening on any
hello world
```

Using `tcpdump`, I can get something like:

```
sudo tcpdump -A -i any port 8098
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
15:14:36.699939 IP localhost.52524 > localhost.8098: Flags [S], seq 4067768558, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 4205840266 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
E..<..@.@.y..........,...u8..........0.........
............
15:14:36.699959 IP localhost.8098 > localhost.52524: Flags [S.], seq 2708887582, ack 4067768559, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 4205840266 ecr 4205840266,nop,wscale 7], length 0
E..<..@.@.<............,.vX..u8......0.........
............
15:14:36.699967 IP localhost.52524 > localhost.8098: Flags [.], ack 1, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 4205840266 ecr 4205840266], length 0
E..4..@.@.y..........,...u8..vX....V.(.....
........
15:14:36.700000 IP localhost.52524 > localhost.8098: Flags [P.], seq 1:13, ack 1, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 4205840266 ecr 4205840266], length 12
E..@..@.@.y..........,...u8..vX....V.4.....
........hello world
```

When all I was interested in was the "hello world" part.